# Try to update an sql row with android

Tags: php, android, sql, sql-server

I tried to update some rows in a sql database. The php function works good but when I applied it on android code it doesn't change anything. When I run my application, my app say me "Update Successfull" but on SQL database it is always the same.

Can anyone help me or guide me to a solution?

Thanks a lot

Here is it my columns of my_table:

```
id | username | password | email | name
```

the code of php function:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'dbpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "UPDATE tbl_user SET name = '$name' WHERE username = '$username'";

mysql_select_db('my_table');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
```

the code of Android activity:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText nome, user;

    private Button  update;

     // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    //php login script
    private static final String UPDATE_URL = "my_site/update.php";

    //ids
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNomePersona);
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserPersona);

        update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdate);
        update.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                new UpdateUserProfile().execute();

    }

    class UpdateUserProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.update_attempt));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String name = nome.getText().toString();
            String username = user.getText().toString();

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json =  jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                       UPDATE_URL , "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Update attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d(getResources().getString(R.string.update_successfull), json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, NewActivity.class);

                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d(getResources().getString(R.string.update_failure), json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

and the activitiy_profile.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewPersona"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textSize="60px" />

                    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            </RelativeLayout>

   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nome Persona" />



        <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNomePersona"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nome Utente" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextUserPersona"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonUpdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="UPDATE" />

    </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are testing if(isset($_POST['update'])) in PHP script. I do not see where you are sending  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("update", update));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution! I hope it can help in future someone....

Here is it a working solution:

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['nameperson'])) {        
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please Enter All Fields";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }


    $query        = " SELECT 1 FROM tbl_user WHERE username = :user";
    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username']
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $query = "UPDATE tbl_user SET name = :nameperson WHERE username = :user";

    $query_params = array(
        ':user' => $_POST['username'],
        ':nameperson' => $_POST['nameperson']
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Username Successfully Added!";
    echo json_encode($response);  

} else {
?>
```

and change in android Activity:

```
    String name = nome.getText().toString();
    String username = user.getText().toString();

    try {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
```

with this one:

```
    String nameperson = nome.getText().toString();
    String user = usern.getText().toString();

    try {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nameperson", nameperson));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user));
```